# Comboxes suddenly don't autocomplete in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, combobox, autocomplete, ms-access-2013

**-------------UPDATE-------------**

By coincidence I actually found an old post, posted a year ago, by myself with sort of the same problem (totally forgot about it). I suddenly remembered that  there was a problem with a reference not being there. Back then I changed everything to late-binding. About a half year ago I created my own COM add-in in C# for my access application, I register this COM object with a script but at this specific user this didn't work. When turning off the specific reference, everything worked again. Conclusion: the bugs / errors were caused by the broken / missing reference...

**----------------------------------------------**

In the category of weird access problems I have another problem. 
In my access 2013 application all the comboboxes don't autocomplete any longer on 1 specific computer. The items are in the list but autocomplete just doesn't work anymore. I have read several other related problems but all those solutions don't work. I have checked / tried the following:

- Repaired the database
- use the DISTINCT keyword in my rowsource (ANSI-92 issue related)
- set the auto-expand property to yes

The weird thing is that other users use the exact same file (it is being copied to local) and at their computers it does work.. 
The file is of type accde. A week ago I had the same problem and I tried to open the same file but instead of opening the accde version I opened the accdb version at this specific users computer and that seemed to work (autocomplete was working again). This worked for about a week but now it is someway corrupted again (I did change the file however and deployed it again recently so that might have to do something with it). '

Besides the combobox autocomplete problem, the same user has also the problem that one specific form doesn't open any longer (again, at the other users it just opens fine), the error is 2467 and it errors on setting the alloweditions of the subform through code. Though it is just weird that this don't causes errors on the other computers so I suspect it is related to the same 'bug' as with the autocomplete.

Anyone experienced the same problems? 
Some additional information:

- the accdb file is coded /created in access 2013
- the users are opening the accde file in access 2013 runtime, the user where the file seems to be corrupted opens the accdb file in the full version of access 2016 (the temporary solution up till now).
- The access application uses SQL Server 2012 as back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

By coincidence I actually found an old post, posted a year ago, by myself with sort of the same problem (totally forgot about it). I suddenly remembered that there was a problem with a reference not being there. Back then I changed everything to late-binding. About a half year ago I created my own COM add-in in C# for my access application, I register this COM object with a script but at this specific user this didn't work. When turning off the specific reference, everything worked again. Conclusion: the bugs / errors were caused by the broken / missing reference...